# Can I direct the detail link in an email template to a specific url

Tags: email-template

We have all of our users login through a proxy server instead of going directly to login.salesforce.com but when I add a detail link (i.e. {!Opportunity.Link}) to an email template/alert the user is directed to the login.salesforce.com instead of our custom URL when they click on the link. This allows them to circumvent the proxy server and log in directly which we don't want!

Secondary question is: Why when the link in an email is clicked does it force the user to login again even if they are already logged in and the session is still live?  Is there a way around this... i.e. user is just taken directly to the record?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Have you enabled "My Domain"? Did you enable "block login from login.salesforce.com"? You'll want to do that to achieve your goals of (a) having the proper link and (b) preventing users from circumventing your proxy.

Comment: We have not yet enabled MyDomain but before we do that I want to make sure that this would not mess up the proxy server login that we have set up.  So I guess the question is:  Can we use MyDomain and have it still route through our proxy server?

Comment: Or maybe asked another way is: Can I use the Proxy server url as the MyDomain address?   So if our proxy login is - https://na24crm.skyhigh.myshn.net - Then would the My Domain look like https://na24crm.skyhigh.myshn.net.my.salesforce.com

Comment: By proxy, I presume you mean a SSO server. MD is perfectly suited to that end, as it allows you to specify a SSO server that ask users must login from. It's really quite convenient. I suggest you try it out in a sandbox first.

Comment: The links will display mydomain.my.salesforce.com (mydomain is whatever you specify), but you can force that domain to redirect to your SSO. If the user is already logged in, it will show the record, and if not, it will force a login with the SSO.

Comment: No I don't think we are talking about an SSO server although we recently implemented Okta.  Our Proxy server routes SF traffic through a cloud security product which we make (Skyhigh Networks)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25937/discussion-between-megachuck-and-sfdcfox).